# WCF - ignore byte array serialization

Tags: performance, wcf, c#-4.0, serialization

I am trying to improve my service performance, I saw that I have CPU peak when my serivce sends the same data to many clients.I thought to ignore the serialization by passing byte array but I saw that wcf serial it to Base64, is there a way to ignore the serialization?

Comment: The data has to be serialized to go over the wire.  If the data is the same every time, perhaps you could serialize it once and stick the serialized copy in a cache or something similar?

Comment: i caouldnt find a way to do that, i am thought to us datacontractserializer to serial the data to byte[] and send it, why does it need to reserial it again?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve your service performance, like Caching and Throttling. First of all make sure what your bottleneck is. It could even be memory taken by server on a pick, anything. Run some load tests to figure it out.

If you want to send you data as binary have you considered to use TCP binding? It can speed up your service a bit as well.

Also make sure that none of the service instance are blocking each other. Consider using re-entry concurrency instanciating of a service.

But since you said "same data" I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is output caching.